# Image preview - Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, uiimageview

The image below is a `cardview` within a feedback section, the purpose is that the user picks an image from the device's gallery and attach it to an e-mail with that image being previewed, I got everything up and running (the user successfully picks an image and send it as an attachment). however I found myself stuck and can't figure how to add a preview to that image (in the grey part of the `cardview` which is an `ImageView`)

PS. aside from the part where the user picks an image from the gallery and attaching it to the email I didn't make any progress in coding the preview part, and for preserving the community guidelines I found it useless to post unrelated code

[image: the cardview]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the uri from the image taken by camera or gallery:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
InputStream imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);
imageStream.close();

imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: that worked just fine, although it needs some more tweaking like scaling and rotating to make it perfectly fit! Thank you!